# How to hide GET method Form or URL value?

Tags: php, mysql, get

I'm using datatables to display the list with "EDIT" button.
running it on localhost.

format I use to echo the details:

```
<a href="student_edit.php?studid='.$row['studid'].'">EDIT</a>
```

displaying the list(datatables) external

```
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array

    $nestedData=array(); 
    $nestedData[] = $row["fname"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["mname"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["lname"];
    $html = '<a href="student_edit.php?studid='.$row['studid'].'">EDIT</a>';
    $nestedData[] = $html;
    $data[] = $nestedData;
}
```

result:

```
http://sample.com/studid?=1
```

To get the data of student:

```
$id_get = $_GET['studid']; //GET THE ID VIA URL
$sql = "SELECT * FROM student_list WHERE id = '".$id_get."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $fname1=$row['FIRSTNAME'];
        $mname1=$row['MIDDLENAME'];
        $lname1=$row['LASTNAME'];
        $gender1=$row['SEX'];
        $addrc=$row['ADDRESS'];
        }
        ?>
```

How is it possible to hide the Id Number in URL?

Comment: you can use session.

Comment: How can you use session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use POST method and a hidden input field for `id`.
Something like,

```
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array

    $nestedData=array(); 
    $nestedData[] = $row["fname"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["mname"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["lname"];
    $html  = '<form action="student_edit.php" method="post" name="form_'.$row['studid'].'">';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="studid" value="'.$row['studid'].'">';
    $html .= '<input type="submit" name="edit" value="EDIT">';
    $html .= '</form>';
    $nestedData[] = $html;
    $data[] = $nestedData;
}
```

To get the data of student:

```
if(isset($_POST['edit']) && $_POST['edit'] == 'EDIT'){

    $id_get = $_POST['studid']; //GET THE ID VIA URL
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM student_list WHERE id = '".$id_get."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $fname1=$row['FIRSTNAME'];
            $mname1=$row['MIDDLENAME'];
            $lname1=$row['LASTNAME'];
            $gender1=$row['SEX'];
            $addrc=$row['ADDRESS'];
        }    
}
```

Comment: but I'm using datatables. displaying it with edit button.

Comment: Hi please do check my update. I added my code to display the tables.

Comment: I thought its not possible to use POST. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

you can use some encryption code to encrypt your parameter which is not understand by user.

```
$myData = array('foo'=>1, 'bar'=>'hax0r');
$arg = base64_encode( json_encode($myData) );
```

http:student_edit.php/parameter=$arg

and back:

```
$myData = json_decode( base64_decode( $_GET['secret'] ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't hide it from URL, what you can do is encrypt the value your want to parse and decrypt it when you want to use it.  You may easily google and found free encryption library, you may try [Encryption](http://www.gilfether.com/phpcrypt/)

It would be better if you mix it with separator and some random value(like timestamp), so your encryption string will not be static.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below.

```
<a data-id="<?php echo $row['studid'] ?>" class="url-click">Edit</a>

<form action="<?php echo 'student_edit.php' ?>" method="post" id="custom-request">

<input type="hidden" id="id" value=""/>

</form>
```

=== Add JavaScript ===

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.url-click').on('click',function(){
    $('#custom-request #id').val( $(this).attr('data-id') );
    $('#custom-request').submit();
 );
});
```

====PHP====

Use $_POST variable instead of $_GET